# DNS issue after upgrading ec2 instance to t2.medium from t2.micro

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns

I have upgraded an ec2 instance from t2.micro to t2.medium, Now the public IP for my instance is changed.

And I have put the new public IP in DNS type A., But services are not accessible when I am hitting with the domain name in the URL. When I hit the services using public IP its working fine.

**Note:** When I check logs I am still getting traffic but don't know why I am not able to access these services.

It's a critical issue. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: What is your DNS records TTL?

Comment: earlier it was 1 day , 5-6 hours back i changed it to 30 minutes in order to upgrade my instance

Comment: If your TTL for a DNS entry was `1 day` then any changes that you make will take apx `1 day` before a client that has cached that entry will go back to your DNS server to resolve again. Making the TTL short and then changing it only affect clients that have not cached your DNS entry. Only make the TTL short if you plan to make multiple changes. If you are just making a single long term change, changing the TTL does nothing for you.

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley You are right. Everything is working fine now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change IP address in DNS you need to wait for propagation of such change (what can take up to 24h) as DNS is distributed system using a lot of cache to reduce load. To reduce that time in future you can try to set TTL for your record to some small number like 60s but please note that TTL is more like hint for DNS clients than restriction so you can still experience problems.

I would suggest to attach Elastic IP address to your EC2 instance - that address is static and you can detach it and attach to new EC2 instance so change in DNS is not required and still you can update/upgrade your EC2 instance.

Comment: thanks @jakub for the prompt reply. Should i wait for 24 hours or i can do something because its a production issue.

Comment: Sadly you can do nothing about your clients because you cannot invalidate their cache. If you have some control about your clients you can try to flush DNS caches on PCs what on Ubuntu looks like: sudo systemd-resolve --flush-caches. Still that doesn't solve problem with caches on DNS resolvers servers like routers or Active Directory servers. I would really appreciate if you could accept my answer :)

Comment: one more thing I am still getting traffic on my upgraded instance, is it because some changes has been propagated.

Comment: That's totally correct as cache problem is really client specific so some part of your clients revoked cache already and some not

Comment: Even i am not able to hit the services, could you tell me how can i do this, just to test and make sure this is the exact issue and will be resolved in 24 hours :)

Comment: sure - try to change your dns resolvers to google 8.8.8.8 as they are updating theirs cache quite often. Also please provide TTL for you A record.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179301/discussion-between-awadesh-and-jakub-bujny).